# Powershell: `GetNetworkCredential().Password` is not displaying all the characters of the password after `AppendChar()`

Tags: powershell, credentials, securestring

I have a cmdlet `Append-SecureString.ps1` which provides padding of a desired length/size to a SecureString with a particular character('o' just for demonstration sake). And I am using another cmdlet `Decode-SecureString.ps1` which obtains the plaintext from the SecureString.

The cmdlet `Decode-SecureString.ps1`

```
#Decode-SecureString.ps1
param([SecureString]$SecureString)
               Write-Information -MessageData "Retrieving string..." -Verbose -InformationAction Continue
                    try{
                    $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
                    $length = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadInt32($bstr, -4)
                    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
                    }
                    finally{
                        if ( $bstr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero ) {
                          [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
                        }
                    }
```

The cmdlet `Append-SecureString.ps1`

```
#Append-SecureString.ps1
param(
[Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential,

[Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
[int]$Length
)
while($Credential.Password.Length -lt $Length){
            $Credential.Password.AppendChar('o')
        }
$Credential.Password.Length
$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
.\Decode-SecureString.ps1 -SecureString $Credential.Password #Custom cmdlet provided above.
```

And the result is:

```
$cred=Get-Credential -Message "Enter the credentials."
$cred.UserName
picachu
$cred.Password.Length
14
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
THISISPASSWORD
.\AppendTo-SecureString.ps1 -Credential $cred -Length 64
64
THISISPASSWORD
Retrieving string...
THISISPASSWORDoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

So, as we see, `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` didnot display the complete string of the $Credential.Password which is a SecureString by the way. But my custom cmdlet `Decode-SecureString` successfully obtained the complete padded string from the $Credential.Password which is the SecureString.

So, can anybody pin out why `GetNetworkCredential().Password` didnot displayed the complete string, and if possible, how do you exactly make `GetNetworkCredential().Password` display the string behind the `$Credential.Password` without using my custom cmdlet `Decode-SecureString.ps1` ?

Comment: `GetNetworkCredential()` cache `NetworkCredential` object. And do not rebuild it when you change `SecureString` in `Password` property.

Comment: Ok. So I need to rebuild another credential. I am posting the solution for the above requirement. I was initially thinking that it may be that it is a read-only property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the cmdlet `AppendTo-SecureString.ps1` to workaround as below. It doesn't require `Decode-SecureString.ps1` to display the characters anymore. The problem was that as @PetSerAl pointed out, the `GetNetworkCredential()` doesnot rebuild the cache for an already existing `PSCredential` object. So I decided to build another credential using the new `SecureString` and return it.

```
param(
[Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential,

[Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
[int]$Length
)
$secureString=$Credential.Password
while($secureString.Length -lt $Length){
            $secureString.AppendChar('@')
        }
$tempCred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Credential.UserName,$secureString
#Comment out  below for returning the new credential.
$tempCred.Password.Length
#Comment out  below for returning the new credential.
$tempCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
#UnComment out  below for returning the new credential.
###Return $tempCred
```

Or, you can skip rebuilding  a new `PSCredential` object and use `NetworkCredential` as below:

```
$tempCred=([System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new($Credential.UserName,$secureString))
#Comment out  below for returning the new credential.
$tempCred.Password.Length
#Comment out  below for returning the new credential.
$tempCred.Password
#UnComment out  below for returning the new credential.
###Return $tempCred
```

Comment: `NetworkCredential` have its own constructor. If only thing you want is to get plain-text password, then you do not need to create `PSCredential` first.

Comment: Right. I will add it to the solution as well.